# use multi level data in EasyUI PivotGrid

Tags: javascript, pivot, jquery-easyui

pivotgrid can get an array of objects. you can choose array fields as rows or columns to create the pivot. :

```
var data = [{

    "ProjectName": "Company Holiday",
    "OrderNumber": "123",
    "Hrs": 8,
    "ResourceName": "Gilly",
    "ForecastMonth": "Dec-16",
    "FcDate":"12-16"
}, {
    "status" : "true",
    "ProjectName": "Company Holiday",
    "OrderNumber": "123",
    "Hrs": 8,
    "ResourceName": "Bill",
    "ForecastMonth": "Apr-16",
    "FcDate":"04-16"
}];
$(function() {
  $('#pg').pivotgrid({
    pivot: {
    rows: ['ProjectName', 'ResourceName'],
    columns: ['ForecastMonth'],
    values: [{
    field: 'Hrs',
    op: 'sum'
  }],
 },
data: data
});
});
```

, but my data are in multi level. and I cant arrange them in one level . this is the simple example of my array :

```
var data = [{
"ProjectName": "Company Holiday",
"OrderNumber": "123",
"item: {
  "Hrs": 8
},
"ResourceName": "Gilly",
"ForecastMonth": "Dec-16",
"FcDate":"12-16"
}, 
{
"ProjectName": "Company Holiday",
"OrderNumber": "123",
 "item:: {
  "Hrs": 8
},
"ResourceName": "Bill",
"ForecastMonth": "Apr-16",
"FcDate":"04-16"
}];
```

now how can I set the row and columns for pivot if there is an object in my array object? 
here is JSFiddle code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zgxege1w/59/